# React native development errors hitting network request catch()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm going to keep this relatively high level as I can't seem to re-create it in the demo app... But I'm having the weirdest problem in React Native on iOS.

When there is an error thrown during the execution of the React Native code in dev mode, it is caught by a random `catch()` block from an old `fetch` request that completed in the past. This fetch block has a `.done()` and terminates.

This then causes a very weird series of errors:

1st: `ExceptionsManager.js:70 Warning: There is an internal error in the React performance measurement code. Did not expect componentDidUpdate timer to start while render timer is still in progress for another instance.`

2nd: `ExceptionsManager.js:55 Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null`

3rd: `ExceptionsManager.js:70 Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null`

Comment: It might be related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6949 Looks like it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: Yep, looks like it no longer happens after updating to react 0.31.0

Comment: @AlekHurst you sure? I steel seem to have this issue...

Comment: The first one happened to me when I forgot to pass a property to a child component that used the property without checking if it exists

Comment: 'Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null' happened to me once when I was missing an ES6 import for a component I was using and a setState() call happened that would have added it to the page.